# Is there an imbalance between males and females in: problem-solving speed, aptitude to group work and emotional influence on actions?

Tags: psychology, gender

According to pop-psychology book ["Men Are from Mars, Women Are from Venus"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Men_Are_from_Mars,_Women_Are_from_Venus) written by relationship counselor John Gray, men and women think and feel in fundamentally different ways and should learn said differences in order for their relationships to thrive.

I couldn't find specific quotes available online (though I have the physical book) but I did find a [summary](http://www.wikisummaries.org/Men_Are_From_Mars,_Women_Are_From_Venus) of it, which I hope can give you a sufficient understanding of the general tone of the book.

Putting aside the relationship advice contained in the book, what piqued my interest was the claim made by Gray that men and women possess strongly different thought patterns and emotional behaviours, a claim which he does not sustain with any reference to research articles or other kinds of scientific evidence. Gray's assertions prompted, as a response, a book by Prof. Deborah Cameron called ["The Myth of Mars and Venus: Do men and women really speak different languages?"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Myth_of_Mars_and_Venus), which - among other topics - replies that most of the differences named by Gray are social myths and stereotypes.

I'd like to know if there are any studies (possibly peer-reviewed) that prove or refute some of the claims in the book, specifically these:

- men have better problem-solving abilities than women (they are more focused than women when clearing tasks);
- men are less inclined to work in groups than women;
- women's actions are less rational and more emotion-driven than men.

Comment: You need to focus this down to a verifiable claim (one aspect which is claimed to be different) -- e.g. "spatial awareness"

Comment: I have specified the three claims I am interested in. If my question needs more improvements I am ready to work on it.

Comment: A long time ago I saw a show in which practical experiments were shown. Males and females were made to play a car racing game. Males were more eager to take risks and were more concentrate. Females on the other hand showed signs of nervousness like blinking eyelids many times and were more cautious.

Comment: In another show on discovery channel an experiment was performed in which several boxes were to be arranged in the back of the car. Males remembered the pattern of the boxes well. While Females had a better memory -- they could remember the names better than men. So one can say females have strong memory whereas Males have good problem solving or analytical capability. It is not that males are better than females. It is just that both are different from each other. If males are good in one thing then females are better in some other.